# iOS UITableView numberOfRowsInSection in tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath give BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I have receive a EXC Bad Access error when I enter the if statement below  `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]`.I'm calculating the `tableView numberOfRowsInSection`  of the UITableView inside the heightForRowAtIndexPath .

**I have got following code to set height for last row of first section**

```
-(CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;

            if (indexPath.row==lastRowIndex) {
                return 44.0f;

            }else{
                return 100;

            }

        }else{

            return 100;
        }


}
```

**I got the error as below image**

[image]

**I didnt find this method appropriate**

[iOS UITableView numberOfRowsInSection BAD ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912540/ios-uitableview-numberofrowsinsection-bad-access)

```
- (int) myNumberOfRowsMethod{
    // Here you would usually have some underlying model 
    return [self.myContactsOrWhateverArray count];
}
```

Comment: cant we use some thing like tableView numberOfRowsInSection that method works better then array count

Comment: what you have in `numberOfRowsInSection` method? i think instead of `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;` you can use `[self myNumberOfRowsMethod] - 1;`

Comment: I didnt want to use myNumberOfRowsMethod  i want to use some better methods so bro

Comment: Can you Post your - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section method's Code?

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    if (section==0) {
        return [ storeArr count]+1;
    }else{
        
        return [ [[itemArr objectAtIndex:section-1] objectForKey:@"itemList"]count];
    }
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling numberOfRowsInSection: from heightForRowAtIndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381805/calling-numberofrowsinsection-from-heightforrowatindexpath)

Comment: How many no.of rows are there for 1st section ?

Comment: can u check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part

Answer (score 2):

Try this method 
`[self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]` instead of `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]`. It's works fine.

Comment: can u check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part

Comment: can i get that too bro

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to following

```
-(CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1;

            if (indexPath.row==lastRowIndex) {
                return 44.0f;

            }else{
                return 100;

            }

        }else{

            return 100;
        }
}
```

Comment: what the difference in your answer compare to the question , already condition is validated isEqual to 0\

Comment: can u check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part

Answer (score 1):

Please Try With This.
Make one Global NSinteger firstSectionCount;
and then try with this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (section==0){
    firstSectionCount = [ storeArr count];
    return [ storeArr count]+1;
}else{
    return [ [[itemArr objectAtIndex:section-1]   objectForKey:@"itemList"]count];
}
```

and then,,,,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section==0) {
    if (indexPath.row==firstSectionCount) {
        return 44.0f;

    }else{
        return 100;

    }
}
else{
      return 100;  
}
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: can u check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
-(CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            long lastRowIndex = [self.yourArray count]-1;

            // other wise use this line
           // long lastRowIndex = [self.yourArray lastObject]-1;

            if (indexPath.row==lastRowIndex) {
                return 44.0f;

            }else{
                return 100;

            }

        }else{

            return 100;
        }
}
```

Because this `numberOfRowsInSection` not work `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

Comment: i will try that bro and will reply u

Comment: can u check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 -(CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        NSInteger lastRowIndex = yourArray.count - 1; 

        if (indexPath.row==lastRowIndex) {
            return 44.0f;

        }else{
            return 100;

        }

    }else{

        return 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692692/what-could-we-do-in-case-of-custom-cell-in-viewforheaderinsection-to-reload-part